# Weird thing happening with font on mobile

Tags: html, google-font-api

I'm using Google font on my site, and on my mobile version of the site, there is a bug when letter "s" and "t" are next to each other like this:
[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: That is not a “bug”, but a **ligature** ... https://glyphsapp.com/tutorials/ligatures

Comment: Didn't even know that concept of ligature exists.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug but typographic feature called ligature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature

> In writing and typography, a ligature occurs where two or more graphemes or letters are joined as a single glyph

Comment: ok, thanks, it could be the problem of the wordpress plugin that I'm using then..

Comment: no, there is no problem at all. When "s" and "t" are next to each other it is shown as on your picture because there's ligature defined in the font you are using.

Comment: can you link to one or two?